# Is there a list of API's that TOR browser blocks

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting, javascript

I was looking for some kind of documentation on what API's and scripts does the TOR browser blocks (mainly as a defense for fingerprinting). I have come across the [Design and Implementation document of the Tor Browser](https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#fingerprinting-linkability) but was confused whether the list of API's mentioned in the document are all of the API's that get blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor doesn't block APIs (this is virtually impossible and probably not what you want to do), Tor blocks web pages which addresses match a given check on a blacklist or entire types of content like JavaScript, iframes and fonts. There is no list as such.